# Make Table Column Draggable React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a column draggable in a React table, but I am having some issues. I have the code that was used to make the rows draggable and I pretty much have to replicate the same to the columns since I am pretty new to React, I still don't quite understand all the concepts.

I would really appreciate any help that could be given. Below I will post the code I have on the component.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export function GridHeader({
  headerData,
  headerFunctionDispatcher,
}) {
    
    //INIT OUR STATE OR RESET
  const initDragInfos = {
    draggedItem: {},
    draggedFromIndex: null,
    draggedToIndex: null,
  };

  //MANAGE OUR STATE
  const [dragInfos, setDragInfos] = useState(initDragInfos);

  //DRAG START
  const newOnDragStart = (e, currentItemId) => {
    // var ctr = document.getElementById("colId" + currentItemId);
    // e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ctr, 0, 0);
    //console.log(e.clientX, e.target);
    //console.log(currentItemId);
    //We find the current Item Index
    const currentItemIndex = headerData.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === currentItemId
    );
    console.log(currentItemIndex);

    //SET
    setDragInfos({
      ...dragInfos,
      draggedItem: headerData[currentItemIndex],
      draggedFromIndex: e.currentTarget.dataset.position,
    });
  };

  //DRAG OVER TO CATCH THE "TO INDEX"
  const newOnDragOver = (e) => {
    //SET
    setDragInfos({
      ...dragInfos,
      draggedToIndex: e.currentTarget.dataset.position,
    });
  };

  //WHEN I DROP THE ITEM AT THE NEW POSITION
  const newOnDragEnd = (e) => {
    //CALL THE HEADERFONCTION RELATED TO DRAG AND DROP
    headerFunctionDispatcher(e, "dragDropCol", dragInfos);
    setDragInfos(initDragInfos);
  };

    return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {headerData.map((item) => {
                    //console.log(item.id);
                    return(
                        <th
                            key={"grid-header-" + item.id}
                            id={item.id}
                            draggable
                            onDragStart={(e) => newOnDragStart(e, item.id)}
                            onDragOver={(e) => newOnDragOver(e)}
                            onDragEnd={(e) => newOnDragEnd(e)}
                        >
                        {item.name}
                        </th>
                    )
                })}
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
        
}
```

I believe the problem should be on:

```
setDragInfos({
      ...dragInfos,
      draggedItem: headerData[currentItemIndex],
      draggedFromIndex: e.currentTarget.dataset.position,
    });
  };
```

and

```
setDragInfos({
      ...dragInfos,
      draggedItem: headerData[currentItemIndex],
      draggedFromIndex: e.currentTarget.dataset.position,
    });
  };
```

more specifically on the draggedFromIndex.

I define the headerFunctionDispatcher in another component, where I also manage the state:

```
const [header, setHeader] = useState(GRID_HEADER);


  const headerFunctionDispatcher = (e, name, options) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    switch (name) {

      case "dragDropCol":
        setHeader((prevHeader) => {
          //INIT
          let newHeader = [...prevHeader];

          //DELETE ITEM FROM OLD POSITION
          newHeader.splice(options.draggedFromIndex, 1);

          //ADD ITEM TO NEW POSITION
          newHeader.splice(options.draggedToIndex, 0, options.draggedItem);

          //RETURN MODIFICATION AND RENDER THE APP
          return newHeader;
        });
        break;

      default:
        console.log("To be created");
    }
  };
```

If anybody could help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out the solution. I was missing some fields on the return. As such, by adding some of them, the columns moved to the right place. I also added a property to create a shadow when moving the column.

```
 return (
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {headerData.map((item,index) => {
                    console.log(item.id);
                    return(
                        <th
                            style={{opacity: dragInfos.draggedItem.id !== headerData.id ? "50%" : null}}
                            key={"grid-header-" + item.id}
                            id={"colId" + item.id}
                            data-position={index}
                            draggable
                            onDragStart={ (e) => newOnDragStart(e, item.id)}
                            onDragOver={(e) => newOnDragOver(e)}
                            onDragEnd={ (e) => newOnDragEnd(e) }
                        >
                        {item.name}
                        </th>
                    )
                })}
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
```

This allows for the column to change the opacity when dragged.

```
style={{opacity: dragInfos.draggedItem.id !== headerData.id ? "50%" : null}}
```

Also, by mapping out the index and adding the line below, the column gets dragged to the correct position.

```
 data-position={index}
```

I hope if someone has this doubt, although I know this code is very specific and maybe not the best example, that by looking at the implemented logic you can do the same easily.

Cheers everyone